# Android User Interface

Tags: android, dialog

[image]

Hi Friends,i want alert dialog like(only text not radio buttons) same as in the image but i don't want radio buttons, i need only text, How can i do that, please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 final CharSequence[] items = {"One", "Two", "Three"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
             // Do something with the selection
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            // Do something when ok pressed
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            // Do something when cancel pressed
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
final CharSequence[] version = {"Jelly Bean", "IceCream Sandwich", "Honey Comb", "Ginger Bread"};
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ad.setTitle("Choose your version");
ad.setMessage("You can set messag here");
ad.setItems(version, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int intVersion) 
{

}
ad.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() 
{
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int arg1)          
{

}
}
ad.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() 
{
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int arg1) 
{
}
});
ad.setCancelable(false);
ad.show();
```